# Root collar excavation cost

Tags: trees

Does anyone know approximate cost for doing root collar excavation on trees? We have several "mulch volcanoes". Plenty of info on the internet about using an airspade or air knife and removing the girdling roots, but I'm trying to get a sense of what it would cost and not seeing anything come up in google. Thanks.

Comment: What type of tree?

Comment: I am lost as to what you are asking, what the problem is; soil mammals, girdling roots, root 'collar' or root 'cellar'?  We need to know what tree you are talking about, what started your concern, what you want to accomplish and as much detail as you could possibly provide.  Including pictures, zone, your place in this world...excavation means big equipment, tree removal, root cellars...root collar means you see roots encircling the trunk at or below the soil line and need to know how to cut those roots.  Mulch volcanoes means moles and gophers (in the middle of winter)?  Interesting.

Comment: I guess part of the factor in cost will be if you're renting the airspace equipment, or hiring somebody to do it.  I've airspaced a few times, and it's not a pleasant process, depending on your structure it can go fairly quickly or be very slow.

Comment: I'm voting to close: Questions seeking price-shopping assistance are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. See: Teaching a man to fish, garden, and … shop, https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285/teaching-a-man-to-fish-garden-and-shop

Comment: I did some research. About $250/day to rent airspade and compressor (DIY). About $700 to have a company do the excavation on 6 trees. Doesn't really matter the type of tree; more on diameter, how much to excavate. If you're unfamiliar with the concept, google "mulch volcano". It's a big problem.